# Vector with elements equal to a function evaluated at a, a+1,... b .in R

Tags: r, function, vector

I have two integers a and b (with a less than b), as well as a function f(x). Is there a way of getting the vector

```
x<-(f(a), ..., f(b))
```

from R without having to explicitly having to write it out? as my a and b vary.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: How do you get the list of integers? I'm thinking along the lines of `sapply(c("a", "b"), FUN = function(x) f(get(x)))`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can try something like the following :

```
foo <- function(x) x+1

a <- 1
b <- 5

sapply(a:b, foo)
```

But note that if you need this kind of behavior, you should vectorize your function, ie make it accept a vector as argument instead of a single integer. In my previous example, the `sapply` is not needed at all : `+` is vectorized, so I can just do :

```
foo(a:b)
```